# 404 after upgrading artifactory from 6.20 to 7.6.2

Tags: artifactory

I am getting 404 accesing to https://my-dmain/ui/. If I try to access to https://my-dmain/artifactory it redirects to https://my-dmain/ui/ with 404. No log errors, only one warning:

> 2020-07-10T08:06:04.535L [35m[tomct][0m [WARNING] [                ]
> [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig]
> [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - A docBase
> [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/artifactory.war]
> inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored 
> 2020-07-10T08:06:04.540L [35m[tomct][0m [WARNING] [                ]
> [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig]
> [org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor] - A docBase
> [/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access.war]
> inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm it, can you try to access the Artifactory using the server IP and port, like HTTP://1.2.3.4:8082? If you are able to access the Artifactory UI using the server IP and Port, I believe you need to tweak the reverse proxy being used.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. It gets stucked trying with ip and port. The migration was ok, i can see the screen with the animation while booting up..but then..404.

Comment: do you observe any log entries with 404? Can you share the router-service.log file? Can you share the output of this curl, curl http://localhost:8046/router/api/v1/system/health and curl localhost:8046/router/api/v1/topology/health from the Artifactory server?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that with Artifactory 7.x the reverse proxy configuration is different. In [this KB article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-recommended-nginx-reverse-proxy-configuration-for-artifactory-7-x-and-above/) you can find a working NGINX configuration.

One easy way to generate such configuration is to bypass your reverse proxy and go to Artifactory directly, there in the UI you will be able to log in, head to HTTP settings, and generate a new Apache or NGINX config.